# Regularity of $\nu $ for $g \in L^1 (\mu) $ and $d\nu = g d\mu $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu $ is a positive regular measure on Baire $ \sigma$-algebra of  a locally compact Hausdorff space $ S $ , $ 0\leq g \in L^1 (\mu) $, and $$\lambda (E)= \int_E  g d\mu $$ then $\lambda$ is also a positive measure.  Can we say that $\lambda $ is a regular measure?

Comment: Yeah! @ Crostul

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can. Let $A \subset S $ be Borel and $\epsilon >0$. Because of $g \in L^1 (\mu) $, there is $\delta >0$ with $\int_E |g|d\mu <\epsilon $ as soon as $\mu (E)<\delta $. One way to see this is to approximate $g $ by step functions.

We let $E_n= \{x \mid g (x)\geq 1/n\} $. Note that $\mu (E_n)<\infty $ for all $n $ and $\nu (A)=\lim_n \nu (A \cap E _n) $. Thus,  for $n $ large, we have $\nu (A\cap E_n)>\nu (A)-\epsilon $.

By regularity of $\mu $, there is a compact $K\subset A\cap E_n \subset A $ with $\mu ((A\cap E_n)\setminus K)<\delta $. Hence $\nu ((A\cap E _n)\setminus K)<\epsilon $, which easily yields $\nu (A\cap E_n)<\nu (K)+\epsilon $.

This shows inner regularity of $\nu $. But for **finite** measures,  by taking complements,  it is not hard to show that inner regularity implies outer regularity.

Comment: Why do we need the sequence $ A\cap E_n $?  Can't we direct say that By regularity of $\mu $, there is a compact $K \subset A $ with $\mu ((A\setminus K)<\delta $. Hence $\nu (A\setminus K)<\epsilon $, which easily yields $\nu A<\nu (K)+\epsilon $?

Comment: @User: That depends on your exact definition of regularity. My definition (taken from Folland) is that we are inner regular on all **open** sets (and outer regular on all Borel sets). This implies inner regularity on sets of finite measure. Also, if $\mu (A)=\infty $, you could maybe find $K\subset A $ compact with large measure $\mu (K) $, but still $\mu (A \setminus K)=\infty $. Thus, I intersect with $E_n $ to get finite measure.